# QBluetooth: Slow BLE characteristics scan

Tags: linux, qt, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have compiled and runned LowEnergyScanner from Qt 5.8 QBluetooth examples on my Linux laptop. And I am faced with the fact it is very long scans the device characteristics. In some cases, I generally can not wait for the end of the scan. NRFConnect on Android, as well as a simple Python script using bluepy on my Linux laptop scan characteristics very quickly. So it's not a hardware problem.

Comment: Try to manually initiate a service scan using *gatttool* on your PC and measure the time. I believe Qt does add very little overhead, since it's not using its own BLE stack. Thus, if it's slow using gatttool as well, try out different BLE-hardware on your PC, to make sure its not your dongle/chip thats bad, rather than longer timeouts or even a bug in BlueZ or Qt.

Comment: Maybe you have a very large connection interval?

Comment: I have tried to set connection interval to 7.5 ms via Qt, but nothing changed.
Scan via gattool works fine.